# Intentionally creating duplicate migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I'm creating an application that users can add and remove entities from. The application generates models, migrations and migrates the database. Effectively something like this:

```
`rails generate model #{model_name}`
`rake db:migrate`
```

When a user removes a model, I clean up the files and generate a new migration that drops table.

At this point I'll have a list of migrations that are something like:

20110515130423_create_customers.rb
20110515130445_create_houses.rb
20110515130457_drop_customers.rb

No problem - everything works. Migrating through the full set of them adds and then removes stuff, but it's alright.

My problem comes up when someone tries to add a model they'd previously added. Rake aborts saying:

> Multiple migrations have the name CreateCustomers

What should I do? The approach I'll try first is trying to detect loops like this and then clear out all the migrations. Is this going to leave the migrations database in a weird state?

Thanks for your help - I know this is a bit of an oddball situation ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think it's a bad idea delete table and later recreate it you may create migration like `alter_table_customers` where you should do necessary changes in DB

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and for most apps I'd agree. However, this is a weird self-modifying application where users choose what models exist in the app

Comment: well in that case I would write my own generator and overwrite old migrations instead of creating new